# Loudness control LUFS level adjustments

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, broadcasting, loudness

Is there a tool that can adjust the loudness level of a video?

for example I need to make the loudness to be -23 LUFS with max deviation of 0.5 lu.

is there a simple tool/cloud service that doesn't cost too much, that can do this ?

Comment: Be careful. Depending on the length of the asset and the content, you may not want to use a tool that dynamically adjusts to target loudness over the course of the asset. If you are dealing with long assets (>2 minutes) and/or you own the content, then adjusting like that is fine. However, with short assets or when you are only playing back someone else's content, like commercials on a TV station, you should only do a simple level shift (linear normalization) to meet your target loudness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FFmpeg's [loudnorm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm) filter can be used. Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -af loudnorm=I=-23:LRA=1 -ar 48000 out.mp4
```

The loudness range (LRA) should be `2 x max deviation`.

Also see the [ebur128](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ebur128-1) filter for measuring loudness.

Comment: I'm getting an error message No such filter: 'loudnorm', do I need to install it somehow?

Comment: Filter was added in May '16. Get a current version of ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html